# python parser args argument only used when the value of another augment is a specific one

Tags: python, argparse

I've looked online and it seems like subparser would be the answer but I couldn't figure out how to use them to suit my need.
here's what I have so far:

```
def get_config():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='data mining mining argument parser')
    parser.add_argument('mode', type=str, choices=['apriori', 'eclat','closed','rare','arm'], help='algorithm mode')
    parser.add_argument('minimum_support', type=float, default=3, nargs='?',help='minimum support of the frequent itemset')
    parser.add_argument('minimum_confidence', type=float, default=0.6, nargs='?',help='minimum confidance for the association rule mining')
    parser.add_argument('algo',type=str, default='apriori', const='apriori',nargs='?', choices=['apriori', 'eclat','closed','rare'], help='itemset algorithm')
    parser.add_argument('data', type=str, default='data.txt',nargs='?', help='file containing the transactions')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    return args

def main():
    args = get_config()
    start_time = time.time()
    if args.mode == 'arm':
        result = run_association_rule_algorithm(args.mode,args.minimum_support, args.minimum_confidence,args.algo,args.data)
    else:
        result=run_itemset_algorithm(args.mode,args.minimum_support,args.data)
    duration=time.time() - start_time
    print("Time duration: {}" .format(duration))
```

for example, when I run:

`python3 main.py arm 2 0.6 eclat data.txt`
or:
`python3 main.py rare`
(without giving the minimum support value and so letting it use the default one)
things work fine

however once I try to give values through the command line to run  `run_itemset_algorithms()`
I get this error:

`usage: main.py [-h] {apriori,eclat,closed,rare,arm} [minimum_support] [minimum_confidence] [{apriori,eclat,closed,rare}] [data] main.py: error: argument minimum_confidence: invalid float value: 'data.txt'`

if I understood correctly the float it's expecting is the minimum confidence, which isn't needed unless the mode is arm.

*EDIT:*

```
def get_config():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='data mining mining argument parser')
    parser.add_argument('mode', type=str, choices=['apriori', 'eclat','closed','rare','arm'], help='algorithm mode')
    parser.add_argument('minimum_support', type=float, default=3, nargs='?',help='minimum support of the frequent itemset')
    parser.add_argument('data', type=str, default='data.txt',nargs='?', help='file containing the transactions')
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')
    parser_ = subparsers.add_parser('a', help='association rule mining subparser')
    parser_.add_argument('minimum_confidence', type=float, default=0.6, nargs='?',help='minimum confidence for the association rule mining')
    parser_.add_argument('algo',type=str, default='apriori', const='apriori',nargs='?', choices=['apriori', 'eclat','closed','rare'], help='itemset algorithm')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args
```

This works fine and I'm a bit embarrassed that it took me a hot minute to figure out how subparser works. Now I want to know if there's a way to go from this cmd line:

`python3 main.py arm 3 data.txt a 0.4 eclat`

to something like this, sans the subparser and in a diffrent order:

`python3 main.py arm 3 0.4 eclat data.txt`

Comment: Did you take a look at [sub-commands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) ?

Comment: Yeah, I did. I ended up just making two .py files instead as it would suit my need.